# image in R dashboard

Tags: r, image, embed, shinydashboard

I am trying to embed an image in R dashboard

```
tags$img(src="pic.png",width="100px",height="100px")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[This is how output come](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUjw4.jpg)

Any suggestions how to solve this problem.

Comment: where is you `pic.png` is located? It should be located in a folder called `www` at the same level where you start your app.

Comment: `pic.png` is in the same folder, where my project is started. But I don't know where is `www` folder located.

Comment: create a `www` folder and move the png into it. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem resolved.